# Can't pass iterator to a class method in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following simple class:

```
template <class T> class ListWrap
{
    std::list<T> m_List;
    explicit ListWrap(std::initializer_list<T> data)
    {
        Set(data);
    }
    void Set(std::initializer_list<T> data)
    {
        m_List.clear();
        m_List.insert(m_List.end(), data);
    }
};
```

This works fine, I can instantiate a new object  `ListWrap` using an initializer list. Now I also want to allow to set `m_List` from another list or iterator, and to use that from a copy constructor.

So I tried to add the following:

```
// copy constructor
explicit ListWrap(const ListWrap& Other)
{
    Set(Other.m_List.begin());
}
void Set(std::iterator<std::list<T>, T> Iterator)
{
    m_List.clear();
    m_List.insert(m_List.end(), Iterator);
}
```

However, now when I try to compile I get the following error:

```
error C2664: cannot convert argument 1 from
   'std::_List_const_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<int>>>'
to 'std::initializer_list<_Ty>'*
```

This error message refers to the call to `Set()` in the new copy constructor. So it seems it tries to use the "old" `Set()` method with the initializer list instead of the second, "new" version of `Set()` that receives an iterator.

Any ideas what I am missing here?

Comment: Which overload of [`std::list::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/insert) are you trying to use?

Comment: @alexolut Frankly I don't care too much, I just want to insert the content of list `Other` into `m_List`.

Comment: For copying purpose, just use `m_List = Other.m_List;` inside copy-ctor. If you want to copy by iterators - you need a pair of them (begin and end).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// copy constructor
explicit ListWrap(const ListWrap& Other)
{
    Set(Other.m_List.begin());
}
```

`Other` is const reference, so `Other.m_List.begin()` is a **const** iterator.

Try `std::iterator<const std::list<T>&, T>`, or `std::list<T>::const_iterator`, for the type of the argument of the `Set` function.

**Edit:**

Here's a [working code](http://ideone.com/bH7PcQ).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

template <class T> class ListWrap
{
public:
    std::list<T> m_List;
    explicit ListWrap(std::initializer_list<T> data)
    {
        Set(data);
    }
    // copy constructor
    explicit ListWrap(const ListWrap& Other)
    {
        Set(Other.m_List.begin(), Other.m_List.end());
    }

    void Set(std::initializer_list<T> data)
    {
        m_List.clear();
        m_List.insert(m_List.end(), data);
    }

    //typename std::list<T>::const_iterator also works as argument type
    void Set(decltype(m_List.cbegin()) beg, decltype(m_List.cbegin()) end)
    {
        m_List.clear();
        m_List.insert(m_List.end(), beg, end);
    }
};

int main() {
    ListWrap<int> l({1,2,3});
    ListWrap<int> l2(l);

    cout << l2.m_List.size() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Apparently `std::list::insert` needs to have three arguments when using iterators from another list, but not from an initializer list. Might as well put `const std::list<T>&` as argument of `Set`, and do `m_List = arg` as indicated in the comments.

Comment: Your first suggestion still leads to the same error message, and your second does not work, because the compiler says `const_iterator` is an unknown identifier. How can I correctly use a `const_iterator` as parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Please check below solution. You must inform the compiler that const_iterator is a typename becuase you are using template parameter.

`void Set(typename std::list<T>::const_iterator iter)`